# How to make all the TextView childs to changed the color of text?

Tags: android

I have a `LinearLayout`, `mRoot`, and it has two child of `TextView`, such as

```
private TextView mNameView;
private TextView mValueView;
```

and I also set these `TextView` with `ColorStateList`. Now, the question is when I press the `mRoot`, those `TextView` can't change the color of text.

But when I make the `mRoot` as the item of `ListView`, then when I press the item, it can change the color of text.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: when these `TextView`(s) in `mRoot` you set any `ClickListener` on the `TextView`(s)?

Comment: Have you tried overriding/creating a custom textview class?

Comment: override which method to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `android:duplicateParentState` attribute to `true` in your `TextView` declarations in XML.

Comment: Hi, Brian. another questio. when I setBackGroundDrawable to mValueView with selector, and when user press mValueView, how to make it change it backgroud? Because I use setDuplicateParentState to mValueview, now user press the mValueView, it can't change its background according to selector? can you help me?

Comment: ListView backgrounds are handled differently. You use the `android:listSelector` (`lv.setSelector(selector);`) attribute to set backgrounds on list view items.

Comment: Hi, Brain. I can't catch it. Could you explain it with some demo?